# Check first login attempt of user in wso2 IAM

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

Is there anyway to identify how many times user has logged in in wso2?

We have a use case where we want to give option to user to reset password after first login?
We are using wso2 IAM.

Answer (score 0):

You can integrate ELK Analytics Dashboard inoder to identify the number of login attempt of a user(https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/elk-analytics/elk-accessing-the-analytics-dashboard/). Furthermore inorder to reset the password  there are several methods we can follow. Which can refer through (https://is.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/guides/password-mgt/forced-password-reset/#offline-password-reset)